# What were the historical reasons why Revelation was included in most Christian canons?

Tags: revelation, canonicity

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation#Canonical_history):

> Revelation was the last book to be accepted into the Christian biblical canon, and even at the present day some Nestorian churches reject it. It was tainted because the heretical sect of the Montanists relied on it and doubts were raised over its Jewishness and authorship, and it was not until 419 that it was included in the canon.

Is this the full story of why it was accepted late (reaction against Montanists, doubts over its Jewishness and authorship), and what justification was there for it's final inclusion over against these doubts?